# Hadoop build error 127

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

I get the following error building hadoop for my raspberry pi cluster

`failure goal org.codehaus.mojo:native-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-7:javah (default) on project hadoop-common: error running javah command: error executing command line. exit code:127`

I tried several times and also tried to use different configs after finding two workarounds. One said, that java path won't be correct what isnt the case for me. Second said I have to get a different maven version, which I had already installed. I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is still having this problem, it is probably due to "*The command line is too long.* problem as pointed out in [mailing list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-common-dev/201702.mbox/%3CDM3PR18MB079583B2B7578530E7657FDDE14C0@DM3PR18MB0795.namprd18.prod.outlook.com%3E).

The suggested solution was to change the maven repository path $User\.m2\repository to a shorter one in {M2_HOME}\conf\setting.xml

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue due to "The command line is too long" and fixed it by changing the maven m2 location in settings.xml.

```
<localRepository>c:\\.m2</localRepository>
```